# Проблема со инициализацией строк

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, информатика

Как мне исправить свой код? Он должен выводить строку, инициализированную первыми `n` символами строки, введённой пользователем, но он не выводит вовсе ничего. Не могли бы вы мне помочь, пожалуйста?

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main () {
 char str[99];
 int n,i;
 int len = strlen(str);
 printf("Enter a string:");
 scanf("%s",str);
 printf("enter n:");
 scanf("%i",&n);
 if (n > len)
 {
 n= len;
 }
 char* new_string = malloc(n+1);
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   new_string[i] = str[i];
 }
 new_string[i]='\0';
 printf("String:%s",new_string);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вчера задавали вопросы на русском, а сегодня что случилось?

Comment: @こきん: Возможно, ТС за ночь выучила английский. Завидую такой скорости!

Comment: @こきん Вам то какое дело

Comment: `int len = strlen(str);` -- в этот момент строка `str[99]` ничем не инициализирована, содержит мусор, поэтому len может быть любым, это серьезная ошибка. (А что вы хотели получить тут?)

Comment: Также здесь `new_string[i]='\0';` переменная `i` не инициализирована. Следует писать `new_string[n]='\0';`.

Comment: Так у вас С или С++? И еще - `scanf("%s",str);` читает в `str` одно слово, а не всю строку.